# Android How to get talkBack to read text when RelativeLayout is displayed

Tags: android, bitmap, android-relativelayout, custom-view, talkback

I have an activity which adds a custom view to the entire activity's view using the following code

```
activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(newView)
```

in order to have a screen of coach marks/usertips displayed.

My custom view extends from RelativeLayout and in its constructor a button is added at the bottom of the screen which when clicked upon dismisses the view.

I have overwritten the "dispatchDraw" method so that I can add multiple coachmark UI objects (textviews and bitmaps) to the layout at specific locations. These coachmark objects draw themselves on the view using code such as the following

```
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(positioning[0], positioning[1]);
        textView.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, positioning[2], positioning[3], new Paint());
        canvas.restore();
```

ISSUE: When TalkBack is enabled

- when this coach mark view is displayed nothing is read out loud for
  this view
- If the user presses where the textviews and bitmaps are, nothing is
  read out loud

however when the user presses on the button the button's contentDescription is read out loud.

I assume the reason the textViews and Bitmaps are not read out is due to the way they are rendered on the canvas by my code above.

**QUESTION 1:** Is there a way to get the TalkBack to say something out loud when the textview and bitmaps are clicked upon?
- I have tried setting contentDescriptions and focusable for the textviews and bitmaps but this does not make any difference.

**QUESTION 2:** An alternative is to get TalkBack to read out something when the custom view is displayed and this text can summarize all the coachmarks displayed in the screen. I can not work out how to do this, does anyone have any suggestions? 
- I have tried setting my customView to be focusable (setFocasable(true) and give it a contentDescription but this does not work.
- I have tried instigating an action when the custom view is drawn and then adding a content description to the event but this does not work either, i.e.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
    // this is not read out load when the view is displayed, but is read when the view is pressed
    info.setContentDescription("on Initialize Accessibility Node Info User Tips");
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've recently been wrestling with a similar problem.

The short answer is to use `View.announceForAccessibility(text)` when you want TalkBack to be triggered, assuming that you are using Android API 16 or later - see [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#announceForAccessibility%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

However, if you want to support earlier Android APIs, there is a more-involved answer using `View.requestFocus()`, which I have outlined here: [Android: How to force Explore-By-Touch/Talkback to repeat the ContentDescription of the current View in AccessibilityFocus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809471/android-how-to-force-explore-by-touch-talkback-to-repeat-the-contentdescription)

I also suggest you have a look at a couple of bugs I raised against Google's Eyes-Free code, which might save you some wasted effort:

- [[TalkBack] Explore By Touch event does not pass through SeekBar's AccessibilityEvent handling methods](https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/detail?id=375)
- [[TalkBack] AccessibilityEvents ignored when source is not set, and no way to set it](https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/detail?id=379)

Comment: @Sarah Maslin
Did you resolve your problem? I'm interested to know the result.